# How to launch preinstalled android apps from web browser href link?

Tags: php, android, android-intent

I am working on a php/mysql website that runs from the mobile chrome browser on android. I would like to launch native preinstalled android apps from links inside the website(a href links). 
So far i have managed to use the following piece of code and it works for 2 or 3 apps. In most cases it tries to launch something but i usually get the error: "item not found".

```
<a href="intent://viber/#Intent;scheme=skype;package=com.skype.raider;end">Skype</a>
<a href="intent://viber/#Intent;scheme=viber;package=com.viber.voip;end">Viber</a>
```

What i wish is to be able to give the user the ability to directly launch an android app from within my website(web app).
I have read that it is possible by using intent-filter/activity and deep linking although i am not sure how to use intent filters and such under php code.

This webapp is going to be accessible only from android tablets, thus the need for the ability to launch native apps from this specific custom website.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it might be possible, but it's difficult to find out the specific URL you need to use, because you're not the app owner. Let me explain.

When you create an app, you specify intent filters in your AndroidManifest.xml. These intent filters tell Android when your app is able to handle a specific action. For example, if you want that your app open URL links like http://www.example.com then you create your filter as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="www.example.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

Unfortunately there is no way to know which intent filters has defined a specific app. So if you have an idea, you might do some trial and error, otherwise maybe you can try to look for information in the app creator site, or even ask the developer for help on this.

Comment: So it seems that there is an app called "System info for Android" that actually can be used to read the manifest.xml and extract the intent filters. I will try it and see if i will be able to get any useful information and report back.

Comment: All good. As mentioned above, i have used the excellent "system info for android" app and i have extracted the host / scheme and path attributes of certain apps to directly launch them using href links. Unfortunately not all apps use the above attributes and i had to search for alternatives.